# How to get IMEI no from tizen phone using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, tizen

I am building an webapp for tizen but i am not able to readout The IMEI no from phone(tizen) .
I have given this tizen:privilege

```
http://tizen.org/privilege/systemmanager
```

but i get this error

```
"This privilege requires partner level signing key"
```

so to resolve this Issue i gon through all these link and followe all steps , but still can't able to resolve this issue .

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/partner_privileges.htm

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/privilege.htm

how do i set partner level signing key ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you correctly run the patch script, eg.

```
patch.bat partner C:\tizen-sdk
```

The example from your links is slightly misleading.